# How to remove week and Day view buttons from FullCalendar in laravel project?

Tags: javascript, css, laravel-5, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar in my `laravel` project and I want to remove week and day buttons from the header bar.

```
$calendar = Calendar::addEvents($data)
          ->setOptions([ //set fullcalendar options
              'firstDay' => 1,
              'height' => 'auto',
              'themeSystem' => 'bootstrap3',
              'columnHeader' => false,
              'aspectRatio' => 1,
              'allDayDefault'=> false, 

          ])->setCallbacks([
    'eventRender'=> 'function (event, element, view) {
        var dateString = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

        $(view.el[0]).find(".fc-day[data-date=" + dateString +"]").css("background-color", "#FAA732");
     }'
          ]);

      $subset = $data->map(function ($data) {
          return collect($data->toArray())
              ->only(['title','start', 'end'])
              ->all();
      });
      return view('events.calendar', compact('calendar','data'));
```

So, I want to remove those week and day view button s from fullCalendar.

I used `'allDayDefault'=> false` and also `allDay='false'` but both of them are not working.

Answer (score 0):

To disable another button then `Month` you can use `right: 'month'` in your calendar options and `right: ''` for get rid of month button.
***you have to add this following option into your setOption parameter.:***

```
$calendar = Calendar::addEvents($data)
          ->setOptions([ //set fullcalendar options
              'firstDay' => 1,
              'height' => 'auto',
              'themeSystem' => 'bootstrap3',
              'columnHeader' => false,
              'aspectRatio' => 1,
              'allDayDefault'=> false,
              'header' => [
                    'left' => 'today prev,next',
                    'center' =>'title',
                    'right' =>'month'],
              .......
```

Comment: Thank you, addy. Actually, I want to use the calendar in month view and remove week and day view. I tried above code but nothing changed.

Comment: you have to add this as above update.let I know if it does not work.